# Call blocking method from multiple methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I have a websocket in a threaded class calling a method on the on_message function send_conf()

But theres a method on a parallel thread also calling the same function every 10 seconds

I tried using run_in_executor in asyncio but I receive the "The event loop is already running
" error.

What is the best way to call this send_conf() function from both the websocket.on_message and the parallel thread simultaneously without blocking?

```
import websocket, threading, json, base64
import time, requests, threading, asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

class Count(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, apiKey=None, apiSecret=None, curl=None, wsURL=None):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.apiSecret = apiSecret
        self.apiKey = apiKey
        self.curl = curl
        self.wsURL = wsURL
        self.executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(5)

        self.session = requests.Session()

        self.session.headers.update({'user-agent': 'Stacked'})
        self.session.headers.update({'content-type': 'application/json'})
        self.session.headers.update({'accept': 'application/json'})


        self.confirmation = send_conf(0)


    def curl(self, path, query=None, postdict=None, method=None):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        return loop.run_until_complete(self.async_curl(path, query, postdict, method))


    async def async_curl(self, path, query=None, postdict=None, method=None):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        URL = self.curl + '/api/v1/' + path
        req = requests.Request(method, URL, json=postdict, params=query)
        prepped = self.session.prepare_request(req)
        def do_prepped():
            return self.session.send(prepped, timeout=20)
        response = await loop.run_in_executor(self.executor, do_prepped)
        return response




    def send_conf(self, param):
        METHOD = 'POST'
        LINK = 'conf'

        return self.curl(LINK, postdict=param, method=METHOD)



    def active_patching(self, time_period):
        while self.ws.keep_running:
            x = 2 + 2

            self.send_conf(x)

            time.sleep(time_period)


    def run(self):

        def on_message(ws, message):
            if len(message) > 10:
                self.send_conf(message['stat'])

        def on_error(ws, error):
            print(error)

        def on_close(ws):
            print("### closed ###")
            exit()

        def on_open(ws):
            args = []
            # args.append()
            args.append("activity")
            request = {"operation": "subscribe", "args": args}
            self.ws.send(json.dumps(request))
            print(request)
            self.acpt = threading.Thread(target=lambda: self.active_patching(10))
            self.acpt.daemon = True
            self.acpt.start()

        def exit():
            self.exited = True
            self.ws.close()


        self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(self.loop)

        websocket.enableTrace(True)
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(self.wsURL,
                                  on_message = on_message,
                                  on_error = on_error,
                                  on_close = on_close,
                                  on_open = on_open)

        self.ws.keep_running = True
        self.ws.run_forever(ping_interval=30, ping_timeout=10)
        self.ws.keep_running = False
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with defining ordinary synchronous methods that call `requests`:

```
def curl(self, path, query=None, postdict=None, method=None):
    URL = self.curl + '/api/v1/' + path
    req = requests.Request(method, URL, json=postdict, params=query)
    prepped = self.session.prepare_request(req)
    return self.session.send(prepped, timeout=20)

def send_conf(self, param):
    return self.curl('conf', postdict=param, method='POST')
```

Obviously, you can't call either of these from asyncio callbacks or coroutines because they would block the event loop. To safely call such synchronous functions from asyncio (and related code, such as websockets callbacks), use `loop.run_in_executor`:

```
async def some_coroutine(self):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    resp = await loop.run_in_executor(None, self.send_conf, param)
```

Behind the scenes, asyncio will submit `send_conf` to a thread pool, suspend your coroutine, and go about its business of servicing other coroutines while `send_conf` is running in a separate thread. When `send_conf` completes, your coroutine will awaken, response in hand.

On the other hand, if you want to call `curl` or `send_conf` from another thread, *just call them*. Yes, they will block that particular thread until they complete, but that will not affect the asyncio event loop.

With that out of the way, the rest of the answer deals with how to improve the architecture so that you don't need the other thread at all.

---

To start an `async def` coroutine from inside the asyncio thread, e.g. from a websockets callback, you don't need `run_until_complete` - in fact, if you try using it, you will get the "event loop already running" error from the question. Instead, you simply need to call `loop.create_task(self.some_coroutine())`.

This means that you don't need to inherit from `threading.Thread` or spawn your own threads just to run something in the background. As shown above, asyncio *already* allows you to write your code using async functions that look like sequential code running in a separate thread, but without the pitfalls of multithreading. For example, the idiomatic way to implement `active_patching` would be using a coroutine:

```
async def active_patching(self, time_period):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while self.ws.keep_running:
        x = 2 + 2
        await loop.run_in_executor(None, self.send_conf, x)
        await asyncio.sleep(time_period)

def on_open(ws):
    # ...
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(self.active_patching(10))
```

The remaining use of threads is hidden behind the calls to `run_in_executor`, which allows you to easily make blocking calls into `requests`, but without interfering with the asyncio event loop. And if you adopt an http library with native support for asyncio, such as [`aiohttp`](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp), you won't need `run_in_executor` at all.